# Test bash if conditions in the terminal

Tags: bash, shell-script, test

I'm developing a bash script and am spending most of my time on debugging the `if` condition statements. [The reference](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/testconstructs.html) states:

> There exists a dedicated command called [ (left bracket special
>   character). It is a synonym for test, and a builtin for efficiency
>   reasons.

I'm looking for a one liner to test conditions without the need to write scripts.

I currently use:

```
test -f test_file
echo $?
```

But am looking for a one liner approach because it's easy to make mistakes and end up using return code (`$?`) from dome other command.

Comment: How about `test -f test_file && echo file exist`?

Comment: What kind of conditions? Why don't you just paste your `if` condition directly into the terminal? Could you give us some specific examples?

Answer (score 3):

you can do this:

```
[[ ! -f ldap.server.xml ]] && echo 1 || echo 0
```

or if you want just the true condition

```
[[ ! -f ldap.server.xml ]] && echo 1
```

Answer (score 0):

try below one liner

```
test -f test_file && echo "True"; echo $?
```